# MultipartFile(MP4) writing to a folder

Tags: java, spring, backend

What class is there in Java or libraries for video processing (getting video size/length/quality and other stuff), also I wanted to know how to record video(mp4) in a folder?

`@RequestMapping("/uploadVideo") public String handleFileUpload(@ModelAttribute VideoRequestDto videoRequestDto) { }`

```
private MultipartFile video;
private MultipartFile avatarForVideo;
```

Comment: https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper might be an option.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MP4 or any other video format.  You would do the same thing for an image, or a PDF document.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to record video to a file

```
MultipartFile.transferTo(new File(pathToVideo))
```